# Internet Explorer not rendering html returned from JQuery ajax post

Tags: html, ajax, internet-explorer, jquery, rendering

I have a page with an input box whose onkeyup fires a JQuery ajax post based on what was typed (a search field)

The ajax call's posted back html is supposed to populate another div on the page.

Here is the jquery ajax post:

```
var o = $(me.results).empty().addClass("aj3load");

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "text",
  url: me.url,
  data: "cmd="+escape(me.cmd)+"&q="+q+"&"+me.args,
  cache: false,
  complete: function() {
    $(o).removeClass("aj3load");
    me.ls = q;
  },
  success: function(msg){
    $(ajax3.results)
      .html(msg)
      .find("div")
      .click(function(){
        var crs_id = $(this).find(":hidden").val();
        $(ajax3.field).val($(this).text());
        $(ajax3.vf).val(crs_id);
        $(ajax3.results).empty().slideUp("fast");
        ajax3.ls = $(this).text();
        getEventInfo();
      });
  }
});
```

Here is the response from the ajax call when searching for "eve" (per Fiddler):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Date: Thu, 03 Dec 2009 16:16:05 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 882

<div><input type="hidden" value="1000806" />111_Demo_Event_090924</div>
<div><input type="hidden" value="1000811" />123 Test Event oct 12 2009</div>
<div><input type="hidden" value="1000805" />AAA_Demo_Event</div>
<div><input type="hidden" value="1000103" />Developing Algebraic Thinking in Grades 3-5 - 30hr</div>
<div><input type="hidden" value="1000086" />Developing Algebraic Thinking in Grades K-2 - 30hr</div>
<div><input type="hidden" value="1000144" />Facilitating Oral Language Development (Grades PreK-3) - 30hr</div>
<div><input type="hidden" value="1000613" />Free PBS TeacherLine Event</div>
<div><input type="hidden" value="1000088" />Math in Everyday Life for Grades 6-8 - 15hr</div>
<div><input type="hidden" value="1000087" />Math in Everyday Life for Grades K-5 - 15hr</div>
<div><input type="hidden" value="1000163" />Using Multimedia to Develop Understanding - 30hr</div>
```

Now in firefox and chrome all those divs show up fine and dandy but in IE only the first div is displayed in the container div on the page.

Any idea what is going wrong with IE here?

**UPDATE:**
If I put in an alert("hello world"); after I assign the $(ajax3.results).html(msg)... call IE will render the ajax posts response correctly. This isn't a solution just possibly some help in debugging. I don't want to have an alert box mid processing. Also I've identified that this problem doesn't seem to affect IE 8, only earlier versions.

Thanks

Comment: It would be useful if you showed the code in the callback from your Ajax request.

Comment: I copied your divs into a string variable `msg`, then ran `$("#mydiv").html(msg);` with no problem, which leads me to believe the problem is with some other part of the page. Are you sure the AJAX call is returning all those events in IE? You might also consider putting more information about the page in your question (other scripts running, etc.).

Comment: Thanks Jeff. Using Fiddler I was able to see the whole post back value from the ajax call (which I've listed in my question). I'm just really baffled as to why IE will only display the first element returned. Since it works in Firefox and Chrome I assume my javascript is correct (neither ie nor firebug shows any js errors).

Comment: Baffling indeed - all I can recommend is to pare back your script to do the minimum possible and see if you can isolate the cause. I'd start by commenting out the `complete` callback and the part of the code that adds the `aj3load` class, if that hides the div, and see if that helps. Blasted IE - please update this when you figure it out!

Comment: To fix this I just changed the output to options in a select list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a long shot, but what are the styles on ajax3.results? Is it possible it has a fixed height with overflow:hidden? Or you could be hitting a rendering bug...do the other fields show up if you resize the browser (to trigger redraw) after the call?

Comment: Ah ha, if I resize the browser the rest of the expected results show up. The styles applied here are: .aj3results { height: 95px; margin-bottom: 2px; padding: 2px; background: #fff; border: solid #000 1px; color: #000; overflow: auto; clear: both; display: none; } .aj3results div{ cursor:pointer; } .aj3results div:hover{ background-color: #CCCCCC; } Sorry for code in comment. Not a fix but you may be on to something.

Comment: Ok, Thank you very much! If I comment out the overflow:auto; from the .aj3results class it works! However I need to keep the results div constrained to a specific height and it's children divs contained to that with the ability to scroll through them. If I change overflow to scroll I get the same rendering issues.

Comment: You might try adding zoom:1 to your .aj3results class and restore overflow:auto. That might trigger a layout redraw.

Answer (score 3):

Your input tags are not closed.  This may be causing some weirdness in IE.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried closing the input tags like so <input /> and still doesn't render in IE.

Answer (score 3):

Ajax requests are cached by IE. Using your **$.ajax** disable caching. This may just be possibly another reason of the issue.

Comment: Hey sarfraz, thanks for the response. I had since added the cache: false to the ajax post but to no avail. I'm beginning to think I'm going to have to redo the whole page w/o using jquery.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I would do is not use `div`s. A more appropriate element would be `p`. An `ol` would be even better.

Give this a shot.

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>IE Ajax Test<title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function doit() {
            $.get('php.php',
                    function(data) {
                        $('#t').html(data);
                    }
                 );
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
    <p id="t">This paragraph will be replaced.</p>
    <p><input type="button" value="Do it!" onclick="doit();" /></p>
</body>
</html>
```

php.php:

```
<?php
print("<p>text</p><p>text2</p><p>text3</p>");
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Tried changing it to use <p> tags instead of <div> tags but IE still only wants to display the first returned <p> element as well. This is killing me.

Answer (score 1):

Check your dataType parameter in your request.  You're expecting html, back, right?  Try changing that to "html".

Comment: Tried that as well. Still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> call back is: function(msg){
>   $("mydiv").html(msg); } – Ryan

Are you missing the # sign in front of mydiv?  Also try `</input>` to see if it behaves any different than `<input />`.

Comment: Thanks for noting that. I just threw in the "mydiv" as a place holder. My apology. There is nothing wrong with the selector in my script as it works fine in both Chrome and Firefox.
I did try your suggestion of closing the input tag like so <input></input> still won't work in IE.

Comment: I tried the same thing Jeff tried and it worked for me, too.  Can you use Fiddler or a debugger and verify that the response object is what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

I had this bug too using .html() after an ajax query. Could not get it too work in IE6 nor 7 for love nor money, so I just reverted to .innerHTML. Works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I am too facing this weird bug. It got fixed once I changed the doctype to transitional from strict and added
  to the beggining of every ajax response.

On another occasion I realized that IE simply refused to accept  tag in the ajax response. Whenever it use to find it, it stripped off my all the tags in the response leaving only skeletal text

Death to IE.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the issue with the missing modals on my JS created modals on my Rails app.

The only thing that worked for me was removing any fading effect, since the response body was correct. (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/3672)

In my rails app (haml+booststrap), I replace of the div's identifier:
"#modal-window.modal.hide.fade"

per

"#modal-window.modal.hide"

It doesn't not break Chrome, Firefox, Safari and worked on Internet Explorer.