# jQuery .html() function only works in Internet Explorer when Developer Tools displayed

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I have a page where one can add, edit and remove items. This is controlled by a number of Ajax calls to server-side code that updates the data for these items in the backend, and upon success updates the DOM element containing a list of these items. It works fine in the versions of Chrome and Firefox I've tested it in. However, when I test it in IE 11, the update of the DOM element only works when I have the Developer Tools bar open. First off, the code I'm using:

```
function getItemList(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'ajax.cfc?method=getXtrasList&eventGUID=#session.activeUser.activeEvent#',
            async: false,
            success: function(results){
                $('#div-items').empty().html(results);                  
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('there is a problem');
            }
        });
    };
```

It is called on the page load, and also upon success of any functions that send an Ajax call to the server side to add or delete any items in the list. 'Results' is an HTML snippet returned in the Ajax call. I validated that the callback was successful and was returning the expected result. This function works on page load, but doesn't update the DOM element selected when called upon success from other Ajax calls (like one that creates a new item for the list). I started out with the directive `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of the page code.

I did the following to try to troubleshoot this:

1. Removed all console references.
2. Used the following directives and tags (the second set was one I had used to solve a similar problem with jQuery and IE9 and earlier in another project):

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=EDGE">

   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
   <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=EDGE">
   ```
3. Tried using .html(results) and .empty().append(results) instead of .empty().html(results) in the above function.
4. Set the dataType to 'html', and also tried 'json', jsonp' and 'string'.
5. Set async: true. I had it set to false originally to prevent any further interactions until the list was updated.
6. Put an alert() inside of the SIAF called upon success. I added it before and after the selector, and ensured that it wasn't hung up on the .html() function.
7. Wrapped the code in the SIAF in a try/catch block, with an alert() if an exception was thrown.

I am sure, since it works in IE if I have the Developer Tools bar open, that it is a compatibility issue, and have gone over the forums and documentation at the MSDN site, which all tell me that the `<!DOCTYPE html>` directive should have worked, so I'm a bit stumped. Other forum discussions on similar problems indicated that setting the dataType in my Ajax call to 'html' should have worked, since IE often has trouble inferring the correct dataType.

So what am I missing here?

Comment: what does `console.log(results)` show in the `success` method? you might also have some `console.log` or some other code which only works when the console is open and might bring the program to a halt when developer tools window isn't open, but it's probably something else

Comment: I had thought at first it might be a stray console.log() reference as well, and had removed all of them.

I went back and added a console.log() output for the function that serves up the content of the item list, and one to output one of the arguments used by the delete function, to make sure each was firing when expected. On page load, the getItemList() function returned the HTML layout I expected. When I clicked the delete button for one of the items, I got the identifier I expected, and the getItemList() function was called and returned an HTML layout I expected.

Comment: Of course, since I had the console open in IE, it worked as expected. One other condition I tried: there is a modal window that pops up to let you know the add or delete was successful. It is set to be invoked before the item list is updated. I moved that reference to follow the invocation of the getItemList() function. Didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, based on a suggestion under this article: [Internet Explorer not rendering html returned from JQuery ajax post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841047/internet-explorer-not-rendering-html-returned-from-jquery-ajax-post?rq=1). IE was caching the results of the Ajax call made on page load. While it didn't fix this guy's problem, when I added the attribute 'cache: false' to my Ajax call retrieving the item list, it now updates the DOM element with the latest result, rather than the cached one.

Comment: Thanks so much, I had been trying to figure out what my issue was for way to long on why IE was not showing the most current data after ajax call. Finally came across you suggestion!!!